# How to compare the querystring parameters saved in a variable, and save the variable in cookie and compare on each page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the url querystring parameters and compare in the if condition.I am getting both the parameters in a single variable. 
How can I check both the parameters together.
Can anyone please tell me how do I compare both the parameters of the url for example:

http://www.xyz.com/?utm_campaign=freeship&utm_content=COUPON_CODE_HERE

I need to get the parameters "freeship" and "COUPON_CODE_HERE"
Please advice.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function(){

getUrlVars();

var param2 = [];    

if( param2 =("percentoff "  &&  "COUPON_CODE_HERE"))
{
    alert("hi");

}
 if( param2 = ("freeship "  &&  "COUPON_CODE_HERE"))
{
    alert("hello");

}


}); 
function getUrlVars()
    {

        var string1=["utm_campaign"];
        var string2=["utm_content"];

        var string1 = [], hash;
        var string2 = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');

        for(var i = 0; i < string2.length; i++)
        {
            hash = string2[i].split('=');
            string1.push(hash[0]);
            string1[hash[0]] = hash[1];



            param2=(hash[1]);
            //alert(hash[1]);



         }


       return string1;
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready( function(){
        var params = getUrlVars();
        var utm_campaign = params["utm_campaign"];
        var utm_content = params["utm_content"];
        if( utm_campaign === "percentoff" && utm_content == "COUPON_CODE_HERE")
        {
            alert("hi");
        }
        if( utm_campaign === "freeship" && utm_content ===  "COUPON_CODE_HERE")
        {
            alert("hello");
        }
    });

    function getUrlVars() {
        var vars = [], hash;
        var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++) {
            hash = hashes[i].split('=');
            vars.push(hash[0]);
            vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
        }
        return vars;
    }
</script>
```

As per you request these are function for cookie manipulation.

```
CreateCookie("cookie1", utm_campaign , 60);

//Creates client side cookie,
function CreateCookie(name, value, minutes) {
    var expires = "";
    if (minutes) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (minutes * 60 * 1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    }

    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires;
}

//Read cookie value
function ReadCookie(name) {
    var key = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(key) == 0) return c.substring(key.length, c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

//Remove cookie
function RemoveCookie(name) {
    CreateCookie(name, "", -1);
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me how can I save that querystring values into a cookie and get on each page to compare the values?

Comment: How can i get the required cookies from the array?I need only utm_campaign and utm_content to be retrieved. I need to check these values stored as i have done in the above code.

Answer (score 0):

using `document.URL` or `window.location.href` you can get the link in js

then you can get the value with match function and regex:

```
var url = document.URL;
url="http://xyz.com/?utm_campaign=freeship&utm_content=COUPON_CODE_HERE"; // remove this line on the website
var campaign = url.match('utm_campaign=([^&]*)');
var content = url.match('utm_content=([^&]*)');
console.log(campaign[1]); // index 1 is the match between the brackets (the wanted value) as 0 will be the whole matched string
console.log(content[1]);
//if you want you can assign the values to other vars:
// var utm_campaign = campaign[1],utm_content = content[1];
// ** here you can compare  campaign[1] & content[1] or utm_campaign & utm_content **
```

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/CME64/4xa9m/)